# Invariant not strong enough to find the first instance of 'e' in an array

Tags: dafny

I'm studying for my Dafny exam and I can't think of an invariant that is strong enough to solve this problem.

```
Given an array of characters, it returns the index of the first ‘e’.
```

We can assume the input array has an `'e'`.

This is my code so far:

```
method firstE(a: array<char>) returns (i: int)
requires a.Length > 0
ensures exists i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && a[i] == 'e'
{
    i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    invariant forall j | 0 <= j < i :: a[j] != 'e'
    // invariant exists j :: 0 <= j < a.Length && a[j] == 'e'
    {
        if (a[i] == 'e') {
            return i;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour:

```
[‘c’,’h’,’e’,’e’,’s’,’e’] -> 2
```

Any hints on how I can solve this?

Comment: your code looks correct to me. but your specification is not quite right. can you explain where you got the postcondition (`ensures` clause)?

Comment: i thought that's the postcondition that we want. there exists an `i` that is within bounds and at index `i` in the array `a` there is an `'e'` is what i'm going for. is it incorrect?

Comment: I think the postcondition should talk about the *returned* value `i`

Comment: got it to work! thanks so much @JamesWilcox

Comment: should i edit the question since initially, i thought the invariant is where i got it wrong?

Comment: the "stackoverflow thing to do" in this situation, is to post an answer to your own question explaining what you figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invariants are not the problem, it's the postcondition (thanks @JamesWilcox)

```
ensures exists i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && a[i] == 'e'
```

It doesn't account for when the array has no `'e'`.

So this is the code that is verified:

```
method firstE(a: array<char>) returns (i: int)
requires a.Length > 0
ensures if 'e' in a[..] then exists i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && a[i] == 'e' else i == -1
{
    if ('e' !in a[..]) {
        return -1;
    }
    i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> a[j] != 'e'
    {
        if (a[i] == 'e') {
            return i;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```